# Click event not triggered on dynamically created table row checkboxes

Tags: javascript, html, events, onclick

I have a table which is dynamically populated with rows, with one column having checkboxes that should toggle a related property for that specific row.

The issue is, the click event I add to the checkboxes is only triggered on page load - the console produces 3 lines of "False" when page is refreshed. If I check/uncheck the boxes after that, there is no output to the console so I assume the events are not being triggered on click.

I don't want it to trigger on page load, I want it to trigger when the checkboxes are clicked.

Below is a simplified version of my code which produces the problem.

index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="table">
<thead><tr><th scope="col">Toggled</th></tr></thead>
<tbody></tbody>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

main.js:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    AddRow(0);
    AddRow(1);
    AddRow(2);
    
    function AddRow(i) {
        var table = document.getElementById('table');
        var tbody = table.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
        
        var node = document.createElement("tr");
        node.setAttribute("id", i);
        node.innerHTML = `<td><input id='T${i}' type='checkbox' /></td>`;
        tbody.appendChild(node);
        document.getElementById(`T${i}`).addEventListener('click', Toggle(i));
    }
    
    function Toggle(i) {
        if (document.getElementById(`T${i}`).checked) {
            console.log(`True`);
        } else {
            console.log(`False`);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the function Toggle each time you add your event. This is what Toggle(i) does. To just define the function to be called without actually calling it, just use Toggle without the brackets.

```
addEventListener('click', Toggle)
```

However this creates another problem because you would like to pass the parameter i to the function. To get around this, define an anonymous function to be executed for the event, and within that anonymous function, call the Toggle function and pass the parameter:

```
document.getElementById(`T${i}`).addEventListener('click', function() {
  Toggle(i);
});
```

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  AddRow(0);
  AddRow(1);
  AddRow(2);

  function AddRow(i) {
    var table = document.getElementById('table');
    var tbody = table.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];

    var node = document.createElement("tr");
    node.setAttribute("id", i);
    node.innerHTML = `<td><input id='T${i}' type='checkbox' /></td>`;
    tbody.appendChild(node);
    document.getElementById(`T${i}`).addEventListener('click', function() {
      Toggle(i);
    });
  }

  function Toggle(i) {
    if (document.getElementById(`T${i}`).checked) {
      console.log(`True`);
    } else {
      console.log(`False`);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Toggled</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than passing the index into the click listener function I suggest using createElement() instead and add the listener directly to the created element.

This way you have direct access to the element inside the function rather than having to do a DOM query for it.

`<table>` elements also have built in `insert` methods to simplify creating rows and cells

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const table = document.getElementById('table');
  [0,1,2].forEach(AddRow);
  console.log('tbody has ', table.tBodies[0].rows.length, ' rows') 

  function AddRow(i) {    
    const row = table.tBodies[0].insertRow();
    row.id = 'row_' + i;    
    const checkbox = document.createElement('input');
    checkbox.type = "checkbox";
    checkbox.id = `T${i}`;
    checkbox.addEventListener('click', Toggle);
    row.insertCell().append(checkbox)
  }

  function Toggle(event) {
    console.log(`${this.id} checked: ${this.checked}`);
    console.log('row id: ', this.closest('tr').id)
  }
});
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Toggled</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```